# Sharepoint RDL report referring a new cube in the SSAS DB fails to execute the query to a shared data source

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, datasource, cube, rdl

A shared data source, already present in our SharePoint server, - works fine for other old reports, which refer old Cube in the same Analysis Services DB. I don't get, why this new SSRS report using new Cube in the same initial catalog on the same server does not work with exesting SharePoint data source.

At the same time this new report does work, when I run it within Visual Studio on the local PC and it uses old Shared Data Source there - the same one, which works for other old reports in VS! I tried to load this .rds data source file from VS Report Designer to SharePoint, but it does not take .rds as a data source (SharePoint data source files has .rsds extantion and it's xml content differ from that in .rds a bit).

What's wrong with SharePoint Mode for a new RDL referring a new Cube in the same SSAS DB?

P.s.: 
Here is SharePoint's shared data source .rsds file content (no defenite Cube mentioned, only DB name 'OLAP_FD'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSourceDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource">
  <Extension>OLEDB-MD</Extension>
  <ConnectString>
         Data Source=s-dwh-srv-01;
         Initial Catalog=OLAP_FD;
         Integrated Security=SSPI;
         Persist Security Info=true;
         MDX Missing Member Mode=Ignore;
         SspropInitAppName=Report Server;
         Roles=Reader;
         Timeout=300
  </ConnectString>
  <CredentialRetrieval>Store</CredentialRetrieval>
  <WindowsCredentials>True</WindowsCredentials>
  <ImpersonateUser>False</ImpersonateUser>
  <Enabled>True</Enabled>
</DataSourceDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved! My college proposed to switch on SQL Server Profiler, than I ran report from SharePoint again and Profiler showed, that SharePoint connectes to SSAS DB with 'Reader' role and then mistake 'Unknown or unprocessed cube' rises. But the Cube was processed, we checked it. So we went to SSMS, connected SSAS DB and checked permissions for 'Reader' role. It was set to 'None' for my new cube SALES_PIPE! We changed it to 'Read'. After this action my SSRS report on the SharePoint portal started to work!